# Naturally shrinking numbers in subscripts

Tags: subscripts

Consider

```
\[
a_{b^{1}}^{c}\qquad a_{a_{b^{1}}^{c}}
\]
```

[image]

I'm annoyed at how the second "b" is lowered relative to the "a", and a reason for this might be that the second "1" is the same size as the first "1".

I was wondering if there is an elegant solution to this?

Comment: While you could do `a_{a_{b\smash{^{1}}}^{c}}`, you will see that the ambiguity is even more annoying than before.  There are only two natural levels of script shrinkage: `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.  Your 2nd example, by accessing beyond those levels, is forced to present the `1` with the same shrinkage as `b`.

Comment: I guess I will leave this open in case anyone has a better solution, but yours is already good enough for me - thanks!!